# Using Size Classes Inside UIScrollview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout, size-classes

I am developing a application which contains a sign up form. I am developing application using Size classes (1 xib file can be run in all devices including iPad.) in that i have to integrate uiscrollview for next - previous fields. hierarchy of views are like this

Xib File -> UIView -> UIScrollview -> UIView -> UitextFields with UILabel

Check image [image: Details of UIView hierarchy]

How can i set Constrain that can manage this view in all devices.

Without using UIScrollview its working perfect as i have set Constrains but when i have add UIScrollview its stop working..

Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: check my question again.. Actually by mistake i have posted my question without complete details...

Comment: Are you looking for vertical scrolling only, with the label + textfield together filling the available horizontal space?

Comment: yes.. and that using size classes... & Autolayout.. only